# Handling expiration & validation of 2FA codes

Tags: security, jwt, brute-force, two-factor-authentication

I am currently planning a 2FA implementation to require users to provide a code via SMS for some actions, like a login. I will also use tools like Google Authenticator, but I do not want the users to force to download the app, thats why I need to send the codes via SMS (or potentially email) as well.

My plan so far is:

1. User wants to login and requests a code
2. Backend generates a numeric code, stores it hashed in DB and returns the ID (or selector) of the database entry to the frontend
3. Frontend displays a code-input field next to the users email & password
4. Code is sent to the user via SMS / email
5. User has now 5 Minutes to send the selector + code + email + password to the backend where all those get validated

2 Questions about this:

**1) Handling expiration of code**

My first idea was to store the code only hashed like a password in the database, but I would have to implement the 5 minute expiration myself. Of course I could add another column with a timestamp to check the expiration, but I would rather go with something more secure.

Now I am thinking about to store the code inside the claims object of a json web token in the database and set the expiration of this token to 5 minutes. So after the 5 minutes are over, parsing the web token to compare it with the code the user has sent, fails. This would allow me in case of an attack scenario to just change the secret of the web tokens and all existing codes would be invalid instantly.

Is this a good approach? Or do you guys see any problems in this, or are there maybe better ways of handling it? Or is there maybe a library for hashing passwords with an expiration date as well?

**2) Validation & handling brute force attacks**

As I only want to send a 6 or max 8 digit numeric code to the user, I will have to implement some sort of protection against brute force attacks (lets assume that an attacker knows the email & password of the user).

What I want to do:

1. If an invalid code was sent once, increase the failed tries of that specific code db entry += 1
2. If the code exceeds 3 failed attempts, invalidate the code in the database and ask the user to request a new code
3. When a user requests a new code, have him wait 1 minute before he can request a new code, store the date of the last failed attempt as a timestamp in the users db entry as well as the 1 minute delay
4. If the third code fails, store the new timestamp and double the delay to 2 minutes
   ... and so on. After 3 failed codes a JS Challenge (Google Recaptcha) will be required as well.
5. After 5 retries I would lock the account and wait for the user to contact us.

I this a secure approach to handle the validation of the codes?

Comment: I wonder if you have considered adopting one of the authentication-as-a-service systems? Onelogin, Okta, Ping, Auth0, etc. You'll be able to handle FIDO keys, SMS 2f, various federation systems, etc, straight out of the box.

Comment: And, don't forget you must verify the SMS number ahead of time, and prevent evildoers from spoofing that verification.

Comment: Hey Jones, sure, the user has to verify the device upon registration. And yes, I have considered some of those services, but most have drawbacks. Some require an App, some cannot send tokens via email, some are pricy and most of them are storing data the US, where will run into some GDPR issues. Also, I want to understand where the issues in building it myself are and see if my approach is correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overdoing th security of your six-digit verification codes by using JWTs.

No matter how you manage them, you must invalidate them when they expire or when they're used. A good way to do that is to give each code a row in a table including the expiration timestamp. Then DELETE the row for the code when the user presents it. Whenever you look up those codes add `WHERE expires > NOW()` to the query. And routinely DELETE expired rows.

Resisting brute force attacks is straightforward. By the time you're ready to send your user a code, you have already validated their password so you know who they pretend to be. So just keep track of that user's attempts to guess the code. As you suggested, give them three tries. Then make them request another code. If they rerequest more than five codes in a calendar day, lock them out until the next calendar day.

This scheme, by the way, is useful for generating all kinds of nonces. (Numbers used once.) Nonces come in handy for many purposes like password resets by email.